# mysql give one wrong timediff out of 20 right

Tags: mysql, datediff, timedelta

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `Time`,
    `Resolution`,
    HOUR(TIMEDIFF(`Resolution`,`Time`)), 
    TIMEDIFF(`Resolution`,`Time`), 
    datediff(`Resolution`,`Time`) 
FROM Cases;
```

In order to debug, I add the TIMEDIFF without the HOUR before, just to see if the result is different. I use datediff to double check.

The result of the query is:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Time                | Resolution          | HOUR(TIMEDIFF(`Resolution`,`Time`)) | TIMEDIFF(`Resolution`,`Time`) | datediff(`Resolution`,`Time`) |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 2017-01-10 13:35:00 | 2017-01-24 10:52:00 |                                 333 | 333:17:00                     |                            14 |
| 2017-01-12 15:53:00 | 2017-02-21 16:06:00 |                                 838 | 838:59:59                     |                            40 |
| 2017-01-18 09:19:00 | 2017-01-18 13:39:00 |                                   4 | 04:20:00                      |                             0 |
| 2017-01-23 09:00:00 | 2017-01-23 15:08:00 |                                   6 | 06:08:00                      |                             0 |
| 2017-01-24 08:49:00 | 2017-02-20 14:34:00 |                                 653 | 653:45:00                     |                            27 |
```

Actually, it delivers more lines, but the relevant line is the 2 result - 838 hours, which translates to 34.91 days, let's say 35, but the DATEDIFF give 40 and when you do yourself the calculation it is 40 days! 12th Jan to 21st Feb.

All other 21 results are correct.

Any idea why? A bug in mysql?
All responses are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,`Time`, `Resolution`)
```

instead.

It also negates the need to use `HOUR()`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

The result returned by `TIMEDIFF()` is limited to the range allowed for `TIME` values. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

`TIME` values may range from `-838:59:59` to `838:59:59`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html

So you're getting the maximum possible value.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped.